# SQL: Count how many start with a, b, etc

Tags: sql

I have a simple customer table with Id, FistName, LastName.

I need to know how many Lastnames start with A and B, etc.
to get something like

```
A,12
B,3
C,45
.
```

.
.
I know `select count(Id) from [dbo].[customer] where last_name LIKE 'A%'` will give how many start with A, but I would not like the idea of doing this for every letter.

Ideas?

Comment: When asking a SQL-related question, please do as it suggests in the tag description (hover your mouse over the tag to read it), and add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using. Syntax and functionality differs between them, so it matters which one you're using.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL has `SUBSTRING`  to get the first character.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `group by`.  Most databases support the `LEFT()` function, including SQL Server (which I assume you are using based on the `dbo.` usage):

```
select left(last_name, 1) as first_letter, count(*)
from customer
group by left(last_name, 1);
```

In other databases, you would need to use some version of `SUBSTR()`.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh . . . I assumed it was SQL Server based on the `dbo.` usage.  That said, I fixed the answer.

Comment: @jarlh . . . But your comment was totally appropriate.  I saw the "dbo" and ignored the fact that the question lacked a database tag -- and the answer depends on the database.